# Is it possible to create a custom theme function?

Tags: hooks, theming

I want for example to create a `mytheme_table` function to override `theme_table` etc. (in template.php) but I do not want to use it everywhere in my project.

I need to replace the table with a div or to remove some hardcoded wrappers.

```
$output .= theme('table_custom', array('header' => $header, 'rows' =>
$rows, 'attributes' => array('id' => $table_id, 'class' =>
array('field-multiple-table'))));
```

Comment: what about just rewriting the individual field in a tpl or preprocess function and leave the tables alone ?

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use hooks in your theme functions.   you could create your own function called theme_table_custom()  and use that in your template files.

if for some reason you must use the hook, you could include the original drupal code in the function and include a check for a table id or something, which would then fire your custom code.

Comment: That is the point. I just duplicated theme_table (mytheme_table in my case) into mytheme_table_custom and it does not work. "mytheme_table" will apply everywhere.

Comment: I think I understand.  so you want to use the second solution I mentioned there. keep mytheme_table() and include a check for the table ID or some unique thing such as the node id.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I could do that. Actually I already did something similar for some custom fields..But it is more like plumbing. I was thinking if there is a more elegant solution. If I have 5 forms and 20 custom fields in a theme will be a mess. :)